# Google Cloud Platform - Dataflow submit batch job from python web app. Intermittent access issue when writing staging files to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

**Background**: My web app calls dataflow using a created service account, prior to the Easter weekend this was working fine.
But since then when the job submits and attempts to create the staging folders/files on my google cloud storage bucket (this is the same project as dataflow).

**Issue**: I run into the following issue, to make matters worse it is not even consistent. At the moment I would say around 1 in 4 jobs succeeds and runs fine whilst the other attempts receive the following error message.

```
OSError: Could not upload to GCS path gs://{my bucket name}/{dataflow staging location}/{dataflow jobname}: access denied.
```

This occurs when trying to upload the dataflow_python_sdk.tar

The http error message:

```
{
  "reason": "forbidden"
  "domain": "global",
  "message": "Access denied.",
  "errors": [
    "message": "Access denied.",
    "code": "403",
    "error": apitools.base.py.exceptions.HttpForbiddenError: HttpError accessing "<https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/{my bucket name}/o?&alt=json&name={my dataflow job name staging location}dataflow_python_sdk.tar&uploadType=multipart>: response.... "
}
```

The dataflow pipeline options are as follows:

```
{
  service_account_email={service account email},
  runner='DataflowRunner',
  project=os.getenv('project_id'),
  job_name=<job name> + '-' + start_date_time.replace('_', '-'),
  temp_location=os.getenv('GCP_DATAFLOW_OPTIMAL_N_TEMP'),
  staging_location=os.getenv('GCP_DATAFLOW_OPTIMAL_N_STAGING'),
  setup_file='./setup.py',
  region='europe-west2',
  machine_type=<machine_type>,
  max_num_workers=10,
  profile_memory=True,
  subnetwork=os.getenv('GCP_SUBNET'),
  use_public_ips=False
```

My service account has the following permissions:

- Compute Instance Admin (v1)
- Dataflow Developer
- Dataflow Worker
- Logs Writer
- Service Account User
- Storage Object Admin

The service account json is stored on the web app as a environment variable called `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.

Has anyone ever come across this and if so how did you solve it?

EDIT:

I have looked at the logging more closely and have noticed that, during the attempt to upload the .tar file to google cloud storage. The process has to refresh the access token. 
In failed attempted jobs, it logs the following message twice: 
Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token 
I assume this means that it fails to refresh the access token, as far as I am aware it can only try twice.

I am currently using apache-beam[gcp] == 2.30.0

Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your pipeline is basically working as intended (failing after a certain number of errors) and this seems like a problem with your interactions with GCS, or potentially something to do with the paths which you are getting from the `os.env`. I'd suggest reaching out to support if you cannot diagnose it.